# Modeling a facebook-like chat/discussion between two users using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

**I am trying to model a FB-like chat/discussion between two users using MongoDB.**

I came up with the following BSon "structure" for a **message**:

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    discussionId: ObjectId(...),
    from: {
       id: ObjectId(...), 
       nickname: ‘Joe’,
       thumbnail: ‘xoopp7788ee….jpg’
     },
    to: {
       id: ObjectId(...), 
       nickname: ‘Jane’,
       thumbnail: ‘rtolkj96547cc….jpg’
     },
    text: ‘Hello Jane, How are you today?’,
    posted: ISODateTime(...),
    viewed: ISODateTime(...),
    next: ObjectId(...),
    previous: ObjectId(...) 
  }
```

I did read the [following mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/) but I still wanted to submit my question because my model/problem is slightly different.

First I am not sure whether the `next` and `previous` fields are necessary. Can I use just the `posted` field in order to *thread* the messages?

Second, can having just one document per message pose a performance issue? Would I be better off with several messages per document?

I am looking forward to reading your comments and suggestions.

**edit1** : the `discussionId` would somehow be a **unique ID for a combination of two users**...

Comment: I think this questions belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO:

- `thumbnail` if it references an avatar should be in user profile. If that's a smiley then it should be at the same level as `text`.
- if `from.id` is a user ID, then to save space you don't need to repeat `nickname`. It can be "injected" in UI or at the time it's sent out somewhere if needed. Sometimes duplicating data can be useful, but in this case it's dubious.
- `discussion` collection might already have `from` and `to` per each discussion. In this case you don't have to repeat user IDs in each message. You could keep only `from`.
- If there could be more than 2 people discussing something - group chat, then `from` and `to` does not work. You might have to make 2 arrays of `from` and `to`. It depends on the type of chat you would have.
- `next` and `previous`: usually I would not have them. You can find a discussion thread by `discussionId, from.id, to.id` and sort it by `posted`. Unless you have some very strange way chat works you can delete these 2 fields.
- `posted` has a date and it's ok, but if you want to save more space date is stored in `_id` as well, so you can avoid creating an index and storing an extra field.
- eventually, if you decide to remove `nickname` and `thumbnail` then you can bring `from.id` to a level up as `fromId`.

Overall it looks good. I'm just nitpicking for performance purposes and small improvements.